# Why this Java code by clicking on button NUM0-9 doesn't print out the character?

Tags: java, java-me, lcdui, j2mepolish, java-canvas

Why this Java code by clicking on button NUM0-9 doesn't print out the character?

```
Code:
switch(this.getGameAction(keyCode)){
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM2:
                System.out.println('A');
                break;

            case Canvas.KEY_NUM0:
                System.out.println('B');

        }
```

Even no Error appears. Why?

Comment: Is the keyboard NUMLOCK on?

Comment: see the doc: http://www.j2megame.org/j2meapi/JSR_118_Mobile_Information_Device_Profile_2_0/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#gameactions

Comment: these answers don't enough explain the reason why this code doesn't work. I need more explanation and solvation. More to say: the code was produced in LOW API Canvas in the abstract method keyPressed.

Comment: As I wrote in my reply below, you don't use getGameAction() on the KEY_NUM0-9 values, nor the KEY_STAR and KEY_POUND. Remove the getGameAction() method in the switch method, and just do switch(keyCode), then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use getGameAction() on the KEY_NUM0-9 values, nor the KEY_STAR and KEY_POUND. You do it like this:

```
public void keyPressed(int kc) {
 if (kc == KEY_NUM1 ) {} // key number 1 pressed
 if (getGameAction(kc) == LEFT) {} // left pressed
}
```